# mongoose virtual is not working in jade-lang

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pug

I defined:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    avatar: Number
});
PersonSchema.virtual("avatarUrl").get(function() {
    return "http://example.com/avatar/" + this.avatar;
});
```

and this works in node's code likes:

```
PersonModel.findOne(function(err, person) {
    console.log(person.avatarUrl); // http://example.com/avatar/1
});
```

but in jade template, if I use:

```
img(src!= person.avatarUrl)
```

this would not give what I expect.

Is there any way to make mongoose virtual works in jade?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is not thing to do with jade,
coz I save the "person" object in session, before I save it to session, everything on "virtual" works fine, but not works when I get it from session again.
may be it's something about the session mechanism.

Comment: have you tried the alternate syntax? `#{person.avatarUrl}`?

Comment: I tried it and is still not working.

Comment: any error messages you can share with us? and the render call for completeness...

Comment: No error message. and im sure the "person" object is not null in node and jade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what 'session mechanism' you are using but if its something like [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) then its calling `JSON.stringify(req.session)` before storing. this transforms a mongoose document into a static javascript object with no getters/setters/virtuals or other dynamic abilities. if you want the current values of your virtuals stored in the session as static values as well, you might want to call `req.session.person = doc.toJSON({ virtuals: true })`.

another option is to reify the session person into a MongooseDocument after it is returned from the session.

```
// assume the session has been retrieved already
var person = new Person;
person.init(req.session.person);
req.session.person = person;
console.log(req.session.person.someVirtual); // yay!
```